# PostgreSQL generate and increment alphanumeric series

Tags: sql, postgresql, alphanumeric

as the question says, I need postgresql procedure which will generate Some ids like:

```
AX0
AX1
AX2
.
.
AX9
AXA
AXB
.
.
AXZ
AY0
AY1
.
.
AY9
AYA
AYB
.
.
AZZ
B00
B01
B02
.
.
etc
```

And the proceedure can also generate next id when given previous, like send **AST** and return **ASU**, or **23X** to return **23Y**......etc.

Example: SELECT db.stored_proceedure('AST');

**As a novice, for now all I have is:**

```
with 
letters as
(select chr(i) as letter from generate_series(65,90) i),
digits as
(select lpad(i::text,1,'0') as digit from generate_series(0,9) i)
select l1.letter || l2.letter || l3.letter || l4.letter || d.digit
from       letters l1
cross join letters l2
cross join letters l3
cross join letters l4
cross join digits d
limit 2000
```

**Which only generate something like:**

```
AAAA8
AAAA9
AAAB0
AAAB1
AAAB2
AAAB3
.....
AAAB8
AAAB9
AAAC0
AAAC1
AAAC2
```

Gurus in the house, please help. Thanks

Comment: `order by` is missing in the query. Arbitrary 2000 rows are returned.

Comment: @Serg that wouldn't be enough

Comment: What is the 1st token? What is the last one, if any? Is it of a fixed size (3, as in your example) or variable size? Is there a need of left padding zeros?

Comment: Generating a set of codes and generating a single code that follows a give code are 2 different questions that require 2 different SO posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 3-char value that includes 0-9 and then A-Z you could produce the next value with the query:

```
with p (q) as (values ('000'), ('999'), ('99Z'), ('9ZZ'), ('AST'), ('23X'))
select q, m
from (
  select q, substr(q, 1, 1) as a, substr(q, 2, 1) as b, substr(q, 3, 1) as c from p
) u,
lateral (
  select (ascii(a) - case when a <= '9' then 48 else 55 end) * 36 * 36 +
         (ascii(b) - case when b <= '9' then 48 else 55 end) * 36 +
          ascii(c) - case when c <= '9' then 48 else 55 end + 1 as n
) v,
lateral (select n / 36 / 36 as d0, mod(n, 36 * 36) as r0) x,
lateral (select r0 / 36 as d1, mod(r0, 36) as d2) y,
lateral (
  select chr(case when d0 < 10 then 48 else 55 end + d0) ||
         chr(case when d1 < 10 then 48 else 55 end + d1) ||
         chr(case when d2 < 10 then 48 else 55 end + d2) as m
) z
```

Result:

```
 q    m   
 ---- --- 
 000  001 
 999  99A 
 99Z  9A0 
 9ZZ  A00 
 AST  ASU 
 23X  23Y
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3be30e73382818aa56223392b1247bbb).

Change values in line 1 to see more examples.

Comment: correct, this is really helpful.  Pls can you show me how to increase the length of 'm'? The second column to hold more characters from 3 to 15,

Comment: I mean the alphanumeric of 15, let say: F3H714XP7E00A5T because now when I change to something like it, 'm' column only produce 'F3I'. Instead of F3H714XP7E00A5U

Answer (score 2):

I did a base36 conversion with PostgreSQL a while back.  I thought I had posted it here but cannot find it in my history:

```
with invars as (
  select num
    from generate_series(0, 1000, 1) as gs(num)
), powers as (
  select n + 1 as n,
         (36^n)::numeric as b36
    from generate_series(0,10) as gs(n)
), symbols as (
  select i as dval, chr(i + 48) as dchar
    from generate_series(0,9) as gs(i)
  union all
  select i + 10 as dval, chr(i + 65) as dchar
    from generate_series(0,25) as gs(i)
), indigits as (
  select num, n, floor((num % lead(b36) over (partition by num order by n))/b36) as b36d
    from invars
         cross join powers
)
select i.num, trim(leading '0' from string_agg(s.dchar, '' order by n desc)) as value
  from indigits i
       join symbols s on s.dval = i.b36d
 group by i.num;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a2807fa61fb93a80a90024bcc963175a)*

Comment: This is a great converter. +1 just for the `^` operator. Didn't know it existed!

Comment: Great, lets check

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this, it would create a string that has all the characters in my case with 4 letters and a number. Then you select as many as you need.

The CTE numberletters  defines how many letters there ca be.

this will need some space run with 8 letters.

> ```
> with 
> letters as
> (select chr(i) as letter from generate_series(65,90) i),
> lettersnum as
> (select chr(i) as letter from generate_series(48,57) i
> UNION 
> select chr(i) as letter from generate_series(65,90) i),
> numberletters as
> (select i as num from generate_series(2,4) i)
> SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(l1.letter || l3.letter || l4.letter 
>   || l2.letter,num)  col , LENGTH(RIGHT(l1.letter || l3.letter || l4.letter 
>   || l2.letter,num)) len
> FROM letters l1 CROSS JOIN letters l3 CROSS JOIN letters l4 
> CROSS JOIN  lettersnum l2 CROSS JOIN numberletters
> ORDER By len, col
> LIMIT 30
> ```
>
> ```
> col | len
> :-- | --:
> A0  |   2
> A1  |   2
> A2  |   2
> A3  |   2
> A4  |   2
> A5  |   2
> A6  |   2
> A7  |   2
> A8  |   2
> A9  |   2
> AA  |   2
> AB  |   2
> AC  |   2
> AD  |   2
> AE  |   2
> AF  |   2
> AG  |   2
> AH  |   2
> AI  |   2
> AJ  |   2
> AK  |   2
> AL  |   2
> AM  |   2
> AN  |   2
> AO  |   2
> AP  |   2
> AQ  |   2
> AR  |   2
> AS  |   2
> AT  |   2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=33a5c51999702fa149c015a6cab69f16)*

For incresing you need a lot of con version

> ```
> select substring('PG1' from '[0-9]+$') as num,
>        encode(
>           decode(
>               (
>                   (encode
>                       (substring
>                           ('PG1' from '^[A-Za-z]+')::byteA, 'hex'
>                       )::int
>                   ) + 1
>               )::TEXT, 'hex'
>       ), 'escape'
>       ) as text_
> ```

> ```
> num | text_
> :-- | :----
> 1   | PH
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f821e6d2a5907485b71e9fdf369b8251)*

Comment: This can be the answer i need,  but pls how can I increment a value with the next? Example: (AG + 1) to return (AH). Thanks

Comment: i added a sample how you can increase  the text.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to learn, i will get back